# Attach image to email from iPhone and not embed

Tags: iphone, email-attachments, apple-mail

Does anyone know a way of attaching emails as a separate file from iPhone Mail app instead of embedding them inline?

I send loads of photos a day and I want to download them easier off Outlook later instead of right clicking and saving as for each file.

Appreciate any assistance.

David

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I read that you should remove your signature (because of HTML), but that didn't changed anything for me ...